# NetLogo cannot load CSV before every run

Tags: csv, netlogo

I am very new to NetLogo and trying to import a CSV with state coordinates. I used the code given here and it's working fine. The only problem is that I have to close the Netlogo and run my code to get my output. If I run it again, it doesn't work, unless I close the software!

I debugged my code, and realized that it doesn't enter the `while [not file-at-end?]` loop for multiple runs. This is weird behavior. I have initialized all my lists and variables, and reset all too. Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
to load-physician-file

  file-open "Physician-File.csv"

  while [not file-at-end?] 
  [
  set csv file-read-line
  set csv word csv ","

  set fileList[]

  while [not empty? csv] 
  [
  let $x position "," csv
  let $item substring csv 0 $x
  carefully [set $item read-from-string $item] []
  set fileList lput $item fileList
  set csv substring csv ($x + 1) length csv
  ]

  set State-abbrev item 0 fileList

  if label-states
  [
   create-state-labels 1
    [ 
      set xcor (item 2 filelist - 1.6)
      set ycor (item 1 fileList - 1.6) 
      set size 0
      set label item 0 fileList 
    ] 
    ] 
   ]  
  file-close
end
```

Comment: you say 'code given here' but don't actually provide the code

Comment: By 'code given here', I meant stackoverflow. There is a popular code that I found. I edited the question to include the code.

Comment: stackoverflow is huge and there may well be multiple pieces of code opening files in NetLogo. Good practice would be to show the code (as you have now done) and also link to the question where you found it. That way, your question and the original get linked so that someone else coming along can find the discussion on both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect you are missing a `file-close` or a `file-close-all`.

Perhaps contrary to expectation, `clear-all` does not close files, nor does `file-open` return to the beginning of an already open file.

Comment: I used file-close as well.

Comment: Adding `file-close-all` at the top of `load-physician-file`, before `file-open`, doesn't fix it?

Comment: Okay. It works! [ file-close-all ] works when it is before the [ file-open ] statement. It doesn't work if [ file-close-all ] is before the end statement.  Thanks for your help!